# WinXP computer hangs at boot and then cycles to "F1, F2" screen

Tags: windows-xp, boot, freeze, safe-mode

I have a Dell desktop that is hanging at the Windows XP splash screen and eventually (after about 5 minutes) cycles to a "F1 to retry boot F2 to enter setup utility".

I tried to start the computer in Safe Mode but it eventually cycles to the same "F1, F2" screen.

What are the likely causes and what are the remedies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran DFT on the computer and it shows that the HD is going. That would explain the strange symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

There are very many likely causes, mostly hardware.
Such problems cannot be solved by remote control.

I would take the computer to a qualified repairman.
Or if it's relatively new, activate the warranty (unlikely, given that it's XP).

Comment: Sometimes it's "cheaper" to just solve the problem directly instead of spending ages looking for the cause

Comment: OK. I'll bite. How do I solve the problem "directly"?

Comment: @Ssvarc: Ivo probably meant the hands-on approach. A repairman has the needed tools and spare parts.

Comment: @Ssvarc: for Ivo to get your message you should prefix the message with "@Ivo:".